# SP_Search account help needed

Tags: search

I installed new search service application using powershell. "**sp_sapool**" is the service application pool account which i used. Everything installed fine. Topology is activated, i changed default content access account to be "**sp_crawl**".
But when i changed under "Configure service accounts" following: "Windows service - Search Host Controller" and "SharePoint Server Search" to use "sp_search" account, which is normal domain user account without any rights, my topology is not showing up anymore, instead it says "Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running." 
Do i have to assign some db rights for the "sp_search" account?

Comment: Also, when i go to "manage services on server" i see that Search Query and Site Settings Service is stopped. "Search Host Controller Service " and "SharePoint Server Search" are running. Shouldn't all three be in the running status?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same service account for your 'SharePoint Server Search' service as you do for all other services (MMS, UPS, etc.). This will maximize performance/reduce memory usage. Do not change the Search Host Controller away from the Farm Administrator account.

Comment: I checked now. As soon as i bring back sp_farm to be search host controller account, topology shows up fine. So, what's the catch with search host controller running under another account beside sp_farm? What rights does it need?